# ValueError:Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, cnn, data-science-model

i represented each row in my dateset as a 15552 cell which is spectrogram colored image(72*72*3), that is represent the audio features, 72*72 is the size of spectrogram image and 3 referred to the 3 channels for RGB values. and each colored pixel is represented in 3 cells side by side and the next 3 cells referred to the next colored pixel and so on. and when i create my model i tried to make the input shape as following
`input_shape=(72, 72, 3) to convert the input image to image so i can use it in CNN model.
Here is the code:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
#Let’s treat the Readername column as the output (Y). 
y= dset.readear     
#Simultaneously we will have to drop the column from dataset to form the input vector.
x=dset.drop('readear',axis=1)
# define one hot encoding
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
# transform data
y= encoder.fit_transform(y.values.reshape(-1,1))
#the split ratio of 80:20. The 20% testing data set is represented by the 0.2 at the end.
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

class_names=['A','G','D','u','E','h','k','t','b','m','i','s','fa','n']
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype('float32')
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype('float32')

#the model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(72, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(72, 72, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(144, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(144, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(144, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(14))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])    

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

But always the fit function give my the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 15552)

can any one tell me how can i fix it?

Comment: Each row in your dataset is of shape `(15552)`, whereas you are telling your model that the expected input has a shape of `(72, 72, 3)`. Reshape the data before passing it to your model to make sure that the actual input shape and the input shape defined using the `input_shape` argument are the same.

Comment: Like I said, reshape the input into the image size you want before passing it to your CNN model using [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Comment: i used this x_train= x_train.reshape(72, 72, 3) but i gives me this error ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 311040 into shape (72,72,3)

Comment: and i tried to make it for each one it the numpy array using for loop like this for x in (311040):
 x_train[x]= x_train[x].reshape(72, 72, 3) , but it gives my the following ardor also TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: You are getting the error because you are missing the fourth dimension indicating the number of samples. You can use -1 for this dimension to let numpy infer this dimension.

Comment: OK, many thanks @Oxbowerce it has been worked, but the fit function gives me another error ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 72
  y sizes: 20
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
,Although iam sure that arrays have the same number of samples

Comment: What is the shape of your `x` array? It should be `(20, 72, 72, 3)` but based on the error it seems the first dimension is of length 72 instead of 20.

Comment: each row in the array is 72*72*3=15552 , 20 refer to what ?

Comment: In this case 20 would be the number of samples you would have, since each sample/row has 72*72*3 input values.

Comment: Many thnaks @Oxbowerce it has been worked! add your answer to enable me to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in your dataset is of shape `(15552)`, whereas you are telling your model that the expected input has a shape of `(72, 72, 3)`. Reshape the data before passing it to your model to make sure that the actual input shape and the input shape defined using the `input_shape` argument are the same. You can reshape the input using [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.reshape(x, (-1, 72, 72, 3))
```

Comment: Why do we add -1 or +1 as fourth dimension?

Comment: -1 simply means that `numpy` will infer the number for this dimension given the data and shape of the other dimensions. This is needed to add an extra fourth dimension that represents the number of observations/samples in the dataset.